# Problem installing Android USB driver on Galaxy SII

Tags: android, usb, installation

I want to install the Android USB driver for my Galaxy SII on a Windows 7 Enterprise x64 SP1 machine.

My phone is detected and listed in the device manager as `"Other devices"` and the status is `"The drivers for this device are not installed. (Code 28)"`.

As I want to install the USB driver I choose `"Update driver"` and browse to the directory containing the driver, and here's the problem. Windows doesn't find anything, it just says

> Windows was unable to install your
>   SAMSUNG_Android
>
> Windows could not find driver software
>   for your device.

I can't remember ever having such problem with this... I have set the phone to `"USB-troubleshooting"` (or what the correct term is in English..) and the drivers previously installed for using it as a mass-storage-device are unistalled.

If anyone knows a solution to this problem and could forward it to me I would greatly appreciate it!

Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to install the driver from Kies, maybe...

Comment: This was actually the right approach. I asked a collegue at work who also recently got a Galaxy S II and he advised me to download the Kies application from Samsung homepage and then install the driver from Keis options. The traditional approach won't do with this phone. So you were right! =)

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes the Kies reinstallation itself does not help (as happened in my case). I was not able to Update drivers via Device Manager either. Following procedure worked for me (WinXP Prof SP3 32-bit):

1. I disconnected the phone.
2. I uninstalled Kies and removed all drivers related to phone with use of [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html)
3. I installed Kies
4. I loaded Kies
5. I selected “Tools > Troubleshoot connection error” to force drivers install and waited, operation took several minutes
6. I connected phone in MTP mode (USB Debug mode was off). Windows installed some drivers automatically.
7. I disconnected phone and reconnected it with USB Debug mode on. Windows installed more drivers automatically (including Samsung Android ADB Interface)
8. I restarted the computer.

It seems it is vital not to plug the phone in before Kies installation is finished.

Comment: Thanks for providing an additional solution!

Answer (score 2):

I've tried both JohnyCash and Phils answers, but still didn't manage to fix the problem. After couple lost hours, here is how I fixed it:

Go to device manager, select `GT I9100` from the list, right click > properties, select `Update driver`, then `Browse my computer for software`, then `Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer`, select `SAMSUNG Electronics Co., Ltd.` > `SAMSUNG Android ADB Interface`, and install it.

`adb` was able to see the device after this, finally!

Comment: THANK YOU! I was about to either destroy my S5 or my laptop.

Comment: I totally understand the pain :)

Comment: Yes - this solved it for me.  It appears because those drivers aren't signed they don't get picked automatically by the finder.  By manually choosing the ADB interface driver as described, I'm up and running.  Thanks Marko!   Now time to remove that piece of junk called Kies :)

Answer (score 0):

1) Enable USB debugging on your device.
2) Connect your device with a USB cable to your computer. Your Windows OS (vista or win7) will automatically install the required drivers.
3) You can check of the device is connected by executing `adb devices` from your windows command prompt. It should list the serial no. of your device.

Comment: Hi. This was my innitial approach, but it wouldn't work. Turned out that you needed to use the driver install feature on the Samsung Kies application.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 for a Moto G and Samsung make sure USB debugging is disabled. Plug phone in USB. Windows will connect and install a driver to access phone.

Disconnect phone from USB. Enable USB debugging in developer options.

Connect USB again. No Windows installs ADB drivers. All shoulld work.

Answer (score 0):

Enable usb debugging in developer options in phone.
Connect the phone to Computer.
Install the driver Samsung USB driver from the following site.
http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117

This will solve the issue.